# R: Create a variable based on another variable which counts the rows since first appearance

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I need to create a variable (`V3`) based on two pre-existing variables (`V1` and `V2`). `V1` is the year and `V2` is a dummy variable. I want to create `V3` which counts the number of years since the dummy variable (`V2`) is **1** for the first time in the dataset. See the required output of `V3` below. Notice that when `V1` skips a year from 2005 to 2007, the increment in `V3` recognises that.

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 0 | 0 |
| 2002 | 0 | 0 |
| 2003 | 1 | 1 |
| 2004 | 1 | 2 |
| 2005 | 1 | 3 |
| 2007 | 1 | 5 |

Here's the data:

```
df<-data.frame(V1=c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007), 
               V2=c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

My failed attempt using dplyr:

```
df2 <- df %>%
mutate(V3 = case_when(V2 == 1 ~ V1 - min(V1)))
```

My attempt uses `min(V1)` to capture 2001 instead of 2003.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(V3 = cumsum(if_else(as.logical(V2), V1 - lag(V1), 0)))`

Comment: maybe `min(V1[V2 == 1])` would work!

Comment: Filling out Sinh's idea, `V3 = case_when(V2 == 1 ~ V1 - min(V1[V2 == 1))` should do fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `match` and `pmax` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(V3 = pmax(V1 - V1[match(1, V2)] + 1, 0))

#    V1 V2 V3
#1 2001  0  0
#2 2002  0  0
#3 2003  1  1
#4 2004  1  2
#5 2005  1  3
#6 2007  1  5
```

`V1[match(1, V2)]` returns the `V1` value where `V2` was 1 for the first time. We subtract that value from each `V1`. `pmax` is used to change the negative values to 0.